# Why is my ListView.builder not working? Seems to be an issue with layout, but don't understand why

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a ListView that I am initializing with a builder:

```
ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => ASScoreInfoWidget(
              title: mockScores[index].description,
              score: mockScores[index].score,
              color: mockScores[index].color),
          itemCount: mockScores.length,
        ),
```

That is one of the children inside of a `Column` widget..

There custom widgets are simple enough...

```
    class ASScoreInfoWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final int score;
  final Color color;

  ASScoreInfoWidget(
      {required this.title, required this.score, required this.color});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          title,
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
        ),
        ASScoreWidget(
          score,
          color: color,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


    class ASScoreWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final int score;
  double fontSize;
  final Color color;

  ASScoreWidget(this.score, {required this.color, this.fontSize = 12.0});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Card(
          color: color,
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: Text(
              "$score%",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          "Ally Score",
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: fontSize),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Now whenever I navigate to the page that shows this `ListView` nothing shows anymore and I get this error:

```
════════ Exception caught by scheduler library ═════════════════════════════════
Updated layout information required for RenderAnimatedOpacity#2d73e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT to calculate semantics.
'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart':
Failed assertion: line 2653 pos 12: '!_needsLayout'

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize': RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#964dd NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
#0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:46:39)
#1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:36:5)
#2      RenderBox.size (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1930:12)
#3      RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:177:9)
#4      RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultHitTestChildren.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2775:25)
#5      BoxHitTestResult.addWithPaintOffset (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:787:31)
#6      RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultHitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2770:33)
#7      RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:414:12)
#8      Rend<…>
```

Comment: Where you are calling for changes.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I don't ever edit this list, just making a demo app for now.

Comment: try `flutter clean` and run again, in my demo it is working, should i add it?

Answer (score 0):

Try `flutter clean` and run again, hope it will resolve the issue.

Try to run this snippet:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SergioBost extends StatefulWidget {
  SergioBost({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SergioBostState createState() => _SergioBostState();
}

class Item {
  String title;
  int score;
  Color color;
  Item({
    required this.title,
    required this.score,
    required this.color,
  });
}

class _SergioBostState extends State<SergioBost> {
  List<Item> items = List.generate(
      5,
      (index) => Item(
          title: "item $index",
          score: index * 2,
          color: index.isEven ? Colors.red : Colors.cyanAccent));
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: 5,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => ASScoreInfoWidget(
                title: items[index].title,
                score: items[index].score,
                color: items[index].color,
              )),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          items.forEach((element) {
            element.score += 6;
          });
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ASScoreInfoWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final int score;
  final Color color;

  ASScoreInfoWidget(
      {required this.title, required this.score, required this.color});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          title,
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
        ),
        ASScoreWidget(
          score,
          color: color,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ASScoreWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final int score;
  double fontSize;
  final Color color;

  ASScoreWidget(this.score, {required this.color, this.fontSize = 12.0});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Card(
          color: color,
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: Text(
              "$score%",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          "Ally Score",
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: fontSize),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, its fixed now. I had to wrap the ListView in a container with a height constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass Axis.vertical in ScrollDirection because you are creating columns.

Otherwise, you must construct columns as rows if you want to scroll horizontally.

```
   ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => ASScoreInfoWidget(
                  title: mockScores[index].description,
                  score: mockScores[index].score,
                  color: mockScores[index].color),
              itemCount: mockScores.length,
            ),
```